# Image Protection. Only show image on .mousedown (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am trying to show an image  but make it difficult to save. So the idea is to have an image div and on top of it another div with a background colour (so hiding it). Then display none on the empty div using jquery on mousedown. Thought it would be simple enough.
The addition of the mouse down function in my code seems to always hide the black div.
Any ideas welcome and thanks in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
        .image {
            position: relative;
        }
        .black {
            position: absolute;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            background-color: #000;
        }
    </style>    
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {

           var imageHeight=$('.image img').outerHeight();
           var imageWidth=$('.image img').outerWidth();
           $('.black').css('height',imageHeight);
           $('.black').css('width',imageWidth);

           $('.black').mouseover( function() {
                $(this).css('display','none');
            )}; 
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="image18.jpeg" alt="image" />
        <div class="black"></div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alternatively, does setting the image as a background image to a `div` rather than using an `img` tag also work? This (should) prevent right-click > save, though it's equally easy to grab the image through a variety of other means.

Comment: It can probably be done with basic html/css, by just putting a transparent image on top of your real image; a right-click-save will then result in the user saving the transparent image. That being said, no technique will really stop the "image thief" who knows what he's doing.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just overlay a transparent `div` over the image? It's about the best you're going to get, since if the user goes into their browser's inspector or pulls out a screenshot program, nothing will work anyway.

Example JSFiddle (try right-click, save as on the image): https://jsfiddle.net/ft47Lcsj/

```css
.image {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5LGqY2p.jpg?1" alt="image" />
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It may stop most of people, but I can do following to get image:

1. With Chrome developer tools I can easily get image URL from "Network/Images"
2. Emulate mouse events from code
3. Install Jing, Screencast or any other utility allowing me to capture video from browser tab or make delayed screenshots

Comment: Plus Pinterest and any other service that scrapes content for image tags.

Comment: Yep i agree. Many, many ways to get that image. My concern is only without making their user experience unusual to make it clear that the image is not expected to be downloaded. Losing battle with a lot of clients.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason that it is always hiding the blank `div` is because on your `mouseover` event, you are setting the blank div to be hidden by applying `display: none` but you aren't removing this CSS property on `mouseout`/`mouseleave`.

```
$('.black').mouseout( function() {
    $(this).css('display','');
)};
```